# Can I use Raspberry Pi as a USB speaker?

Tags: pi-3, audio, alsa, pulseaudio, speakers

Now I have

- `A`: Desktop PC with Arch Linux
- `B`: Raspberry Pi 3 with Raspbian Buster connected with a speaker

and I'd like to use `B` as a **wired** speaker of `A`. By "wired", I mean that `A` and `B` are connected via a USB cable or an 3.5mm audio cable (but not via bluetooth).

Is it possible? I can find many explanations how to use a Raspberry Pi as a bluetooth speaker, but cannot find the wired version.

[image]

Comment: RPi have no audio input on 3.5mm but only audio output .

Comment: I think it should be possible on a RPi Zero or RPi4 with OTG USB.. but why would you want to do it? you could get a much superior quality with a usb DAC which just works out of the box. The Sound Blaster Play!3 is very affordable. But maybe you should take a look at Topping and other competitors in the 100-150$ range. Cheers

Answer (score 2):

There is a [`g_audio`](https://developer.ridgerun.com/wiki/index.php/How_to_use_the_audio_gadget_driver) driver which allows Linux systems with USB OTG support to show up as audio devices on the USB host.

You won't be able to do it on a Pi 3 though, you'll need a Pi 4 or a Zero which support OTG.

Answer (score 0):

As Emphemeral stated in his comment, the Raspi has no wired audio input natively except for using I2S with the IO pins. But if you want to use USB or a 3.5 mm audio jack, a sound card might be an option.